# Inline-block and a pixel at the bottom

Tags: css

I have a simple div with a display: inline-block; and a wrap to center it. It appears a pixel at the bottom of the content. Do you know why and how to get rid of it?

Here is the problem to check: http://jsfiddle.net/8S8aH/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
.wrap {
    text-align: center;
    background:red;
}
#content {
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:250px; height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background:whiteSmoke;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `vertical-align` value on `#content`

```
#content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8S8aH/4/

Comment: Likewise. What is this sorcery? How exactly did you find out that this was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: block` for content div

```
#content {
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:250px; 
    height:100px;
    display: block;
    background:whiteSmoke;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8S8aH/2/)

Comment: It works in this specific case that I have simplified. But if I use display block I have to specify the width and the height to center #content. So I have to use inline-block and that is the question.

Comment: ok, So in that case `vertical-align:bottom` seems to be working. have a look http://jsfiddle.net/8S8aH/5/

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer this to clear space in `inline-block` elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud6ap/)

```
#content:after{
    content:'\00a0';
}
```

There are [alternatives](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) as well.

Comment: Can you explain that? why \00a0  ?